# How do i destroy and recreate a highchart

Tags: charts

Hi I am learning how to use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

But I cant recreate a chart after destroying it.

Heres my code so far. If anyone can help that would be great ...thanks

```
    $.getJSON('reports_procedure_count_bar_ajax.cshtml', data, function (chartData) {

        $('#container2').highcharts().destroy();
        // Build the chart
        $('#container2').highcharts({
         // config stuff here

        });


    });
```

Comment: It should build the chart again, unless your config is flawed. Here's a sample that works: http://jsfiddle.net/a2bcp7yg/

Comment: you are right this does work..thanks for your input Raeen